# Get address of embedded directory in wpf

Tags: wpf, windows

I have a `Dll` with a directory named(Gallery with A list of images).I add this `Dll` as resource
to my main application.

I want to get address of (Gallery folder) in main application.
how can i do this?

Comment: Address on the disk or which address you talking about?

Comment: my file embed in a dll i want to get address file in dll

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly ( getting address = getting resource ), then you can try the Windows API [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

if your Gallery folder included with to get basedirectory use this code

```
  System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```